# Sentry Error logging not working as expected in React Native app

Tags: expo, sentry

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the purpose. I am looking for a solution to replace my console.log(errors) in my app as I get it ready for production. I went through the steps to add Sentry functionality to my expo managed work flow project. It seemed to work, it connects, it runs Sentry.init() just fine. But when I try to use Sentry.captureException('some exception') in place of a console.log, the app crashes and I get "Sentry.captureException is not a function". It logs THAT error in my sentry console. So the error is being passed to my sentry project. But from the documentation I'm following, Sentry.captureException should be a valid function? What am i missing? I have also tried Sentry.captureMessage with the same result.

App.js

```
import * as Sentry from 'sentry-expo';

Sentry.init({
  dsn: 'xxxx',
  enableInExpoDevelopment: true,
  debug: true, // Sentry will try to print out useful debugging information if something goes wrong with sending an event. Set this to `false` in production.
});

enableScreens();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AuthNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

app.json expo hooks

```
"hooks": {
      "postPublish": [
        {
          "file": "sentry-expo/upload-sourcemaps",
          "config": {
            "organization": "myorganization",
            "project": "myproject",
            "authToken": "xxxx"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `Sentry.Native.captureException('message')` - as per [these docs](https://docs.expo.io/guides/using-sentry/#install-and-configure-sentry).

Also note that `sentry-expo` supports TypeScript, so if you were to use TypeScript for your project you would get autocompletion and an error when calling the wrong method.

Comment: Oh gosh, how did I miss that. It works now. I have been at this for hours my eyes are crossed. Thank you, thank you. I can finally go to bed.